Who is behind GPS IFD?
I have read multiple standards, namely TIFF 6 (with supplements) and EXIF 2.3, trying to understand the system of Image File Directories (IFD). What I was not able to figure out is GPS IFD, which is mentioned in both EXIF 2.3 (pp. 1, 18, 26, 138, etc.) and 3 (pp. 39, 192). From TIFF 6, I would understand that it's not a baseline but an extension. So it probably evolved as a private IFD, and Japan Electronics and Information Technology Industries Association (JEITA) seems to operate with that, but it's not clearly said that JEITA would be the organization behind it.

IMHO you really need to expand on some of those acronyms.  TIFF, EXIF and GPS are probably well known in the photography arena.  But what are IFD, JEITA and CIPA?  In addition it would be good for you to link to the TIFF and EXIF standards that you mention, as well as explicitly show the sections you mean.  In other words, don't make us work before we can even try to answer your question.  /s

JEITA/CIPA are the writers of the EXIF standard. Wikipedia links: JEITA, CIPA. IFD is Image File Directory, which is part of how EXIF data is structured.

I think you're asking for the historical origins of the GPS IFD fields? There are many fields added over time to the spec. https://exiftool.org/TagNames/GPS.html
I might suggest asking on a more EXIF-focused forum. https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?board=4.0

@ckoerner Well, I don't know. I guess Exiftool is more Exiftool-orientated. Sure, GPS IFD was added during the time, as were other private IFDs. The way I am going is whether all camera manufacturers and GPS login devices would write data to this IFD or not. EXIF describes it, but their standard is hard to understand. So, I am not sure if they standardize this or are just writing about it.

@Juandev the question about who actually adheres to it might be even more difficult to answer than the origin of the standard... sounds like checking some cams that write GPS enriched images.. wait I think my mobile phone can do, will check
